# cmultifileupload model doesnt work when integrating with other model

Tags: yii, submit, cmultifileupload

CMultifileupload working with

```
 <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Create',array('name'=>'Files')); ?>
```

as well it $_POST the data to the controller and saves to db

but then if i use

```
 <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
```

dosent Post any data to the controller

I did tried

```
  $_FILES['Files']
```

no any change

suppose cmultifileupload is modelA and the other mdoelB
  I need to integrate both these model's 
modelB has submit as

```
 <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
```

due which m unable to integrate so the thing is i need both the models in one form and modelB's id to be the Foreign key to modelA to all the images

HOw do i achieve so? Is it possible? please let me know this for the first time am using cmultiuploadfile am working since past a week but then could not figure out whats wrong Please let me know how can i resolve this

Comment: Did you try ` <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'), array('name'=>'Files')); ?>`?

Comment: no @Jurik i'll try and get back to you

Comment: @Jurik worked with <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'), array('name'=>'Files')); ?>`? thank you

Comment: Good, I added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `array('name'=>'Files')` to your function call:

```
echo CHtml::submitButton(
    ($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'),
    array('name'=>'Files')
);
```